# Array of Objects- Increment a column comparing with other column data

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, object

I have a very complex calculation at hand and I am finding it difficult to get it through. Here it is. I have a table.

Table 1: (Name, ID, Location and Sum are the columns of a table)

```
Name | table1_ID | Location | Sum
rick |  1        | Gorets   | 
alex |  3        | hebrew   |
```

Table 2: (City, ID, Sex are the columns of a table)

```
City | table2_ID | Sex
wew  | 34        | M
rfgf | 3         | F
dgff | 1         | M
hgfhg| 1  | F
```

Table 3: (Notice, ID, Flag are the columns of a table)

```
Notice | table3_ID | Flag
hiji   | 1         |  true
asas   | 1         |  false
```

Final OUTPUT Needed for table 1 should be as follows.

Depending on the values of table 2 and table 3, table 1 should look like this

```
Name | table1_ID | Location | Sum
rick |  1        | Gorets   |  4
alex |  3        | hebrew   |  1
```

I will explain you what is the above thing I am trying to achieve. As you can see, the first table column sum is empty. These gets updates based on the entries found in table2 and table3.

Basically. The 'ID' in table1 is searched in 'ID' of table2 and table3. for eg. ID with value '1' is searched in table2 and table3. It finds out that the ID is present 4 times in the 2nd and 3rd table. So it will put the sum value as 4.

Similarly it will search for 3 in the other 2 tables and finds out that it has occurred only once, so it will update 1 in the 'sum' column for ID '3'.

I hope you have got what I am trying to achieve. If I do a console.log for the 3 tables data, this is the result:

Table 1 :- console.log(userinfo);

```
[Object][Object]
 [0-1]
   [0]: Object
     Name: 'rick'
     table1_ID: 1
     Location:Gorets
     Sum:
   [1]: Object
     Name: 'alex'
     table1_ID: 3
     Location:hebrew
     Sum:
```

Similar format of output for other 2 tables. Can someone please let me know how to update the Sum: with the calculation values mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object which gets all counts of the `ID` in table 3 and as input for the count of table 2 and use it as lookup for assigning the sum in table 1.

```js
function count(r, a) {
    r[a.ID] = (r[a.ID] || 0) + 1;
    return r;
}

var table1 = [{ Name: 'rick', ID: 1, Location: 'Gorets', Sum: undefined }, { Name: 'alex', ID: 3, Location: 'hebrew', Sum: undefined }, { Name: 'foo', ID: 42, Location: 'bar', Sum: undefined }],
    table2 = [{ City: 'wew', ID: 34, Sex: 'M' }, { City: 'rfgf', ID: 3, Sex: 'F' }, { City: 'dgff', ID: 1, Sex: 'M' }, { City: 'hgfhg', ID: 1, Sex: 'F' }],
    table3 = [{ Notice: 'hiji', ID: 1, Flag: true }, { Notice: 'asas', ID: 1, Flag: false }];

table1.forEach(function (a) {
    a.Sum = this[a.ID] || '-';
}, table2.reduce(count, table3.reduce(count, Object.create(null))));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(table1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Edit

> what if instead of ID as the column name for all 3 tables, we have table1_ID, table2_ID and table3_ID as the column names. what changes will i have to make to the code pleasE ?

```js
function count(key) {
    return function (r, a) {
        r[a[key]] = (r[a[key]] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    };
}

var table1 = [{ Name: 'rick', table1_ID: 1, Location: 'Gorets', Sum: undefined }, { Name: 'alex', table1_ID: 3, Location: 'hebrew', Sum: undefined }, { Name: 'foo', table1_ID: 42, Location: 'bar', Sum: undefined }],
    table2 = [{ City: 'wew', table2_ID: 34, Sex: 'M' }, { City: 'rfgf', table2_ID: 3, Sex: 'F' }, { City: 'dgff', table2_ID: 1, Sex: 'M' }, { City: 'hgfhg', table2_ID: 1, Sex: 'F' }],
    table3 = [{ Notice: 'hiji', table3_ID: 1, Flag: true }, { Notice: 'asas', table3_ID: 1, Flag: false }];

table1.forEach(function (a) {
    a.Sum = this[a.table1_ID] || '-';
}, table2.reduce(count('table2_ID'), table3.reduce(count('table3_ID'), Object.create(null))));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(table1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: if there is no match- how can i display '-' instead of number 0 as a sum ?

Comment: one last doubt... wat if instead of ID as the column name for all 3 tables, we have table1_ID, table2_ID and table3_ID as the column names. what changes will i have to make to the code pleasE ?

Comment: i updated my question with the last doubt. could you please help me and point out the changes if the column name is not same on all the 3 tables